# Paralleling a TeamCity build

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have an existing TeamCity job with multiple steps that I want to break up into dependent builds so that I can parallelize the steps, as well as take advantage of the configuration level tweaks.

I think I understand how to make build configs depend upon each other.

But I cannot for the life of me understand the what the concept of "artifact" or "artifact path" is.  Clicking on the little folder icon just displays my source tree.  The text area syntax is baffling to me.

My build is conceptually:

0) checkout code
1) mvn package
2) upload to aws
3) run selenium

How should I pass a .war file from 1) into 2)?

No matter what I do I get the "Failed to resolve artifacts from ... " error.

I have three build agents, but I get the same error when I run with just one.

How do I implement the idiom of having a single pipeline from one git sha that passes down artifacts that produces one outcome?

Thanks!

-neil

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple to setup.

Provided that the .war file is being created successfully we need to ensure that the following is done:

1) The .war file is exposed as a build artifact

This requires the Artifact paths setting on the General settings page.

[image]

I normally abstract this to a parameter, so ensure the parameter value is set to the path of the .war file, relative to the working directory e.g. source/output/my.war

Then ensure this is showing up as an artifact after the build configuration has run

[image]

Is this is all setup and being exposed, then we need to consume this artifact in our "deploy to aws" configuration. In the configuration, ensure there's an artifact dependency coming from the "mvn package" build configuration.

[image]

Is this is working as expected, the war file should be in the working directory for the build agent at the point of running the "deploy to aws" configuration (this will have a seperate working directory by default) . If you change the Artifact rules to something like `+:*.war => mydirectory` then this would create a subdirectory in the agent's working directory and the .war file would be in there. You can then reference the .war file using relative paths

Hope this helps